# how to monitor cpu temperature using snmp or lm_sensors and config it with zabbix dashboard?

Tags: snmp, zabbix, temperature, lm-sensors

I'm trying to monitor cpu temperature via snmp and display in zabbix dashborad, but I can't find temperature from snmp , then I saw lm-sensors used for temperature monitoring, so I need better solution for monitor cpu temperature and config it with zabbix via snmp & lm-sensors.

I have installed my zabbix server in desktop(ubuntu 18.04) , zabbix server and agent work properly, and also zabbiz dashbord. And I'm trying to install snmp in another laptop(ubuntu 18.04) and monitor my laptop's cpu temerature via snmp. both machine are in same network and snmp agent work poperly, according to zabbix dashboard(green snmp icon).

I want to show temperature on zabbix dashboard via snmp. can any one help?

Comment: you have to see if there is already a built in image for snmp temp for your device, if there is not then you can look for a template in https://share.zabbix.com/ , if you wont find it there then it means you have to build a template of your own. read about zabbix MIB file and snmp.

Comment: thank you, now i'm woking on build own template. thanks again.